# Can XBee count collisions?

Tags: xbee

I have the task to count the number of collisions in my S1 XBee network and 
I can't figure out how to do it. Are you guys aware if there is such a thing in the XBee arduino API library?
Must stress that I'm not trying to avoid collisions, I'm actually trying to analyze them.

My Setup:
•XBee S1 w/ API 2 (escaped);
•Arduino Uno w/ Shield;

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a question that could be answered by you _reading_ the API documentation?

Comment: I've already tried checking on that but couldn't find it. Maybe in the documentation they use a different denomination. I don't know... But Doesn't it sound a bit weird not being possible to do so?
When talking about collisions Digi always describe it as a CSMA protocol thing and that it detects and avoid them, not helping me at all.

Thank you anyway, I'll check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Transmit Status frames, as they report failures to transmit including CCA (clear channel assessment) failures.  You might also need to look into possible settings on retries, since the XBee may successfully send after a few collisions and not report on it.

Whatever you come up with, you'll probably need to set up an 802.15.4 sniffer to see if the reported number of collisions matches the number you count manually in a packet capture.

Comment: Thank you again Tomlogic! You are amazing dude! 
/**
 * TX STATUS constants
 */
#define SUCCESS 0x0
#define CCA_FAILURE 0x2
#define INVALID_DESTINATION_ENDPOINT_SUCCESS 0x15
#define NETWORK_ACK_FAILURE 0x21
#define NOT_JOINED_TO_NETWORK 0x22
#define SELF_ADDRESSED 0x23
#define ADDRESS_NOT_FOUND 0x24
#define ROUTE_NOT_FOUND 0x25
#define PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE 0x74
I had no idea what CCA meant when I saw it first time, now it fits! 
Thank you !